# compare the length of multiple files using awk or sed

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I want to compare the number of lines of each file and choose the one that contains the maximum number of lines 
 for example

```
filename_V1 |wc -l =100
filename_V2 |wc -l =19
filename_V3  |wc -l =10

myFile_V1  |wc -l =1
myFile_V2  |wc -l =10
myFile_V3  |wc -l =15
```

I will get as result

```
filename_V1
myFile_V3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative with lot's of piping

```
wc -l *_V* | \             # generate the list
sed 's/_V/ _V/;$d' | \     # separate baseline from versions, delete total
sort -k 2,2 -k 1,1nr | \   # sort by names and size (reverse)
sort -k 2,2 -u | \         # get the first by name (max by design)
sed 's/ _V/_V/' | \        # reverse baseline name back to original
awk '{print $2}'           # extract the filename
```

this script assumes the file names are under your control and space or _V won't appear in the base names. Otherwise check out @Qualia's version.

Comment: Very sensible only using the output from `wc`. This isn't going to work on files like `MY_VERSION_V1` or `my file_V1`. Your first match could be changed to `_V[0-9]\+$`. If you tabulate the output of `wc` (as in my updated answer), you can make your replacement `/\t&/`, and then to join back together with `s/\t_V/_V/`, or more thoroughly `sed -E 's/\t(_V[0-9]+)$/\1/'`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that will consider files grouped by their base parts (what comes before the `_Vn`) and print the ones with the most lines from each group.

**EDIT**: Just to point out that the awk script is not suitable if some file names include whitespace (it assumes the second field in the `wc` output is the entire file name).

```
$ cat bf.awk
$2 ~ /_V[0-9]+/ {
    lines = $1;
    file = $2;
    base = file;
    sub("_.*", "", base);
    if (lines > max[base]) {
        max[base] = lines;
        best[base] = file;
    }
}

END { for (base in best) print best[base] }


$ wc -l *_V*
       3 a_V1
       1 a_V2
       4 a_V3
       4 b_V1
       3 b_V2
       1 b_V3
       2 b_V4
      18 total


$ wc -l *_V* | awk -f bf.awk
a_V3
b_V1
```

Comment: Becareful using the glob expansion there, if there are spaces or other special characters `wc` will not get them safely.

Comment: Thanks, @EricRenouf. I'm not seeing any problem with `wc` when files have spaces in them -- can you elaborate? On the other hand, in the awk script, setting `file = $2` obviously fails if there are spaces in the file name! So that's important to be aware of as well.

Comment: you are absolutely right, my bad on the `wc` part of it.  For the `awk` part if a leading space in the output is ok you could get file by setting `$1=""` and then having `file=$0`, though that still wouldn't help with files with newlines

Comment: Your sub command is iffy - remember that `*` is greedy, the file `my_w1_V1` will be compared with `my_anything_else_V2`. Try replacing the pattern with `"_[^_]*$"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
wc -l filename_V1 filename_V2 filename_V3 myFile_V1 myFile_V2 myFile_V3 | \
sort -rg
```

"count lines for each file " `|` "sort them by number" `|` "inverse order"

It also prints the total (which should be the maximum number), but this should be enough for you.

This is a one-liner. I used the `\` separator to make it more clear

Mixes:

```
command_that_spits_files | xargs wc -l | sort -rg
find . -name 'filename_V[0-9]\{1,2\}' | xargs -L1 wc -l | sort -rg | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Comment: Why introduce `tac` when `sort` already has a `-r` switch to reverse the order?

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately I don't have only this number of files it's just an example (in reality I have for each file a different number of version "_V" and I have to choose the version that contains the maximum number  thanks in advance

Comment: It's generally bad practice to parse the output of ls: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs . Use find instead?

Comment: fixed. Never thought iterating `ls` could be so risky, but did know about complications with white-spaces and scripting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk to find the max if you don't want `sort` since that will also report the number of lines, not just the name of the longest file (by line count).

```
wc -l filename_v1 filename_v2 filename_v3 | awk '$2 != "total" {if($1 > max_val) {max_val=$1; max_file=$2}}0; END{print max_file}'
```

so we'll do a `wc -l` to get the counts of the number of lines in whatever set of files we're interested in, then in awk we'll keep track of the biggest number we saw by looking at the first value and storing it, then at the end print out just the filename associated with the max number of lines we saw.

And for good measure we won't count the "total" line

The safest way to find all the files and do this would be to do (with GNU wc):

```
find -type f -name '*_V*' -print0 | wc -l --files0-from=- | awk '$2 != "total" {if($1 > max_val) {max_val=$1; max_file=$2}}0; END{print max_file}'
```

or without GNU's wc:

```
find -type f -name '*_V*' -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l | awk '$2 != "total" {if($1 > max_val) {max_val=$1; max_file=$2}}0; END{print max_file}'
```

and use the appropriate file glob for `-name` in  find.  Also, if you don't want to look at subdirectories add `-maxdepth 1`

Comment: thanks for your answer actually I have for each file a different number of versions  "_V" and I have to choose the version that contains the maximum number for each file thanks in advance

Comment: As long as you don't have spaces or other special characters in the names you could do `wc -l *_v*` or similar globs for the first part

Comment: @malmo I've edited my answer to show how to do multiple files without listing them each individually

Comment: thanks I get an answer like this "wc: unrecognized option `--files0-from=-'
Try `wc --help' for more information."

Comment: Ah, that might be a GNU extension, you could replace that part with `xargs -0 wc -l` instead

Comment: I get in this case only one file the one that contains the maximum number of lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87288/discussion-between-eric-renouf-and-malmo).

Answer (score 1):

```
LARGESTFILE=;MAXLINECOUNT=0;for file in *; do CURRENTCOUNT=$(wc -l <"$file"); if [ "$CURRENTCOUNT" -gt "$MAXLINECOUNT" ]; then LARGESTFILE=$file; MAXLINECOUNT=$CURRENTCOUNT; fi; done; echo $LARGESTFILE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another "one liner":

```
# generate a tab seperated table: name|basename|lines
for f in *_V[0-9]*;do printf "$f\t${f%V*}\t%d\n" $(wc -l < "$f");done |\
    sort -t$'\t' -k3rn    |\ # sort rows by line number descending
    sort -t$'\t' -u -k2,2 |\ # take rows with unique basename in sorted order
    cut -f1                  # take name column
```

This assumes there are no tab or newline characters in your file names, and uses a number of bashisms (`$` escape characters, string manipulation). Unlike most answers here, it doesn't choke on spaces or multiple occurrences of `_` in a file name.

---

#### More efficient version

The original was robust, but generating the table invoked `printf` and `wc` *N* times. This one's a bit uglier, but much faster (200x on my machine):

```
# table is now basename|lines|name
printf "%s\n" *_V[0-9]*           |\ # print every file on a new line
    rev | cut -d_ -f2- | rev      |\ # extract the base name (faster than sed)
    paste - \                        # combine base name and wc output
        <(wc -l *_V[0-9]* |\
        sed 's/^ *//;s/ /\t/;$d') |\ # tabulate wc output
    sort -t$'\t' -k2rn,2          |\ # sort as above
    sort -t$'\t' -u -k1,1         |\
    cut -f3
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for BEGINFILE:

```
awk '
BEGINFILE { base=FILENAME; sub(/_[^_]+$/,"",base); fname[base]; max=0 }
FNR > max { max=FNR; fname[base]=FILENAME }
END { for (base in fname) print fname[base] }
' *
```

You can approximate that in non-gawk with `FNR==1` instead of `BEGINFILE` but then you'd need extra code to handle the case where all files with a given base are empty if that's possible.